# Why does `... | sed 's/^/stdout: /'` print on empty stdin when `... > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')` doesn't?

Tags: bash, sed, zsh, io-redirection, process-substitution

I'm trying to understand what causes the difference in these 2 constructs that I thought were functionally equivalent:

```
$ ( echo foo >&2 ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') | sed 's/^/stdout: /'   
stdout: stderr: foo
$ ( echo foo >&2 ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
stderr: foo
```

EDIT: If I understood user1133275 right, he suggests that `>(sed 's/^/stdout: /')` is not run unless the subshell `( echo foo >&2 )` outputs to stdout. However, that would mean that the following:

```
$ ( echo foo >&2 ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') > >(echo baz)   
baz
stderr: foo
```

should not display `baz`.

EDIT 2: Perhaps also of interest, sed doesn't output `stdout:` on empty input, even when piped:

```
$ sed 's/^/stdout: /' < /dev/null
$ printf "" | sed 's/^/stdout: /'
$
```

Comment: You've tagged with both [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh].  Which one is it?

Comment: @Kusalananda I checked both.

Comment: Regarding your "EDIT 2": `sed` only outputs lines that are fed to it, or that it creates itself. In neither of those two commands are you giving `sed` a single properly terminated line of input.

Comment: @Kusalananda The results are expected, but when reality doesn't seem to follow common sense, it's time to recheck common sense. user1133275's previous answer also seemed to depend on `sed` printing even on empty input, that's why I added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first command,

```
( echo foo >&2 ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') | sed 's/^/stdout: /'
```

in simplified form (using a temporary file to hold the data produced by `echo`):

```
{ echo foo 2>file >&2; sed 's/^/stderr: /' file; } | sed 's/^/stdout: /'
```

I.e., the first `sed` reads what is produced on standard error from the `echo` and writes to standard output and the second `sed` reads and modifies that.

Your second command,

```
( echo foo >&2 ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
```

in simplified form,

```
echo foo 2>file >&2; sed 's/^/stderr: /' file; sed 's/^/stdout: /' </dev/null
```

Here, the `sed` that gets the standard error output produces output while the other `sed` that gets the standard output output (which is nothing) does not produce any output (since it didn't get any input and since it did not insert or append any data).

Another way of formulating it:

First command:

```
( echo foo >&2 ) 2>file
sed 's/^/stderr: /' file | sed 's/^/stdout: /'
```

Second command:

```
( echo foo >&2 ) 2>file >otherfile
sed 's/^/stderr: /' file
sed 's/^/stdout: /' otherfile
```

In short, the second `sed` in the second command never reads anything. In particular, it does not read the output from the first `sed` as in the first command.

---

Using extremely simplified symbols, the first command is something like

```
utility-writing-to-stderr 2> >(something1) | something2
```

where `something1` writes to standard output, which is read by `something2`.

The second command, using the same notation,

```
utility-writing-to-stderr 2> >(something1) >(something2)
```

i.e. `something1` and `something2` is not even connected to each other, and `something2` can not in any way read what `something1` is producing. Furthermore, since `utility-writing-to-stderr` does not produce anything on its standard output stream, `something2` will have nothing to read from its standard input.

Comment: @P_Yadav Ha! It was backwards for me. I was more confused by seeing that `| sed 's/^/stdout: /'` would take input from `>(sed 's/^/stderr: /')`, when `>(sed 's/^/stderr: /')`'s output should be inherited to be the TTY. It seems that the shell assigns a `>()` subshell a different output to what it inherits if it's used as part of a redirection. That different output is that of the command it's redirecting. Indeed, when I asked the question, I thought `sed` was differentiating its input filetype (named vs unnamed pipe?) and oddly outputting to the TTY on empty input.

Comment: @JoL Nothing is outputting directly to the TTY (`/dev/tty`) here. It's the shell that dumps the final standard output stream to the console.

Comment: I made a followup question about that, but I see what I thought was natural behavior was only done by zsh on some cases and never by bash: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/495346/why-is-the-stdout-of-a-subshell-different-if-its-part-of-a-redirection-e

Answer (score 1):

`>` is operating on `( echo foo >&2 )` and  `|` is operating on `>(sed 's/^/stderr: /')` because of the order of redirection in shells. E.G.

```
$ ( echo foo >&2 ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /' > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /') )
stdout: stderr: foo
```

or

```
$ ( echo foo >&2 ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') | cat > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
stdout: stderr: foo
```

vs explicit examples the order in the question

```
$ ( ( echo foo >&2 ) > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /') ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /')
stderr: foo
```

or

```
$ ( ( echo foo >&2 )  | sed 's/^/stdout: /' ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /')
stderr: foo
```

Comment: Do you mean that `sed` is not run unless that subshell outputs? But then why if you replace `sed` with an `echo baz` it does output? Let me edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: I've edited the question to include what I've asked in my previous comment.

Comment: You're right that changing the order of redirections "fixes" the issue, but the part that I was misunderstanding in particular was that these `>()` subshells get assigned same piped output when they're part of a redirection, instead of outputting to the inherited output that is the TTY, like they would if they were not part of a redirection. E.g. `>()` get's a different output when used like `tee >(...) | ...` than when used like `tee 2> >(...) | ...`. I upvoted both answers, but I think I'm accepting Kusalananda's because it more clearly highlights the file descriptor inheritance issue.

Answer (score 1):

The two commands are not equivalent.

The command (1):

```
( one ) 2> >(two) | three
```

Sends the (std) output of `two` to `three` (More about stderr below).

The command (2):

```
( one ) 2> >(two) > >(three)
```

Sends the (std) output of `one` to `three` (stderr goes to `two`).

---

The painful detail is:

Command 1: `( one ) 2> >(two) | three`

- Command `three` is started (`sed 's/^/stdout: /'`) waiting for input on stdin.
- Redirection of `2` (`stderr`) to the `stdin` of `two` takes place.
- Internal redirection of `one` takes place (`echo foo >&2`).
- The command gets executed sending `foo` to `stderr` (nothing to stdout).
- The word `foo` gets redirected from (`stderr` of `one`) to (`stdin` of `two`).
- The command in two gets executed (`sed 's/^/stderr: /'`)
- The now modified output of `two` (`stderr: foo`) is sent to the stdout of `two`.
- The present stdout of `two` goes through the pipe to `three`.
- The command `three` which was waiting for input from the start gets the output.
- The output gets modified adding a leading `stdout:`.
- The final string `stdout: stderr: foo` goes to tty.

Command 2: ( one ) 2> >(two) > >(three)

- The last redirection (`>`) gets built first.
- The command `three` is started waiting for input on `stdin` **only** (`>()`).
- The command `three` gets **only** the stdout of `one`.
- The command `two` is started waiting for input.
- The command `two` gets (**only**) the stderr of `one`.
- The internal redirection of one connects the stdout of `one` to its `stderr`.
- The command `one` gets executed sending `foo` to the `stderr` (of `one`).
- `foo` goes to `two`
- `two` change the string received to `stderr: foo` and sends it to **tty**.
- `three` receives an empty input form the stdout of `one`.
- `three` prints **nothing** (as there is no line to process).

Understand that this command:

```
printf '' | sed 's/^/initial: /'
```

has no output (and there is no way to make it work).

---

Changing the order: Command 3: ( one ) > >(three) 2> >(two)

Makes the output of `two` go to `three` (not the `tty`) detail left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted @Kusalananda's very clear-cut answer, but I venture to (belatedly) add this to his answer, as a small illustration of process substitution at work:

Your second proposition would work with a small typographical change (and a comparatively large change in its faulty logic):

```
  $ ( echo foo >&2 ) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') > >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')
  stderr: foo    # for the well explained reason above
```

But:

```
    v                                          vv
  $ ( (echo foo >&2) 2> >(sed 's/^/stderr: /') )> >(sed 's/^/stdout: /')  
  stdout: stderr: foo
```

Because adding `( )>` as illustrated (or `>( )`, both work fine) actually allows you to create a file via process substitution, whose output can be redirected as input toward `>(sed 's/^/stdout: /')`.

I thought about adding this to illustrate how process substitution can be embedded in another process substitution. For readability I would **not** push it to more levels of embedding. But if for any reason you need to avoid a *pipe* and the associated *shell*, this is a good solution.